# Leaflet polygon object attributes

Tags: arrays, leaflet

Within a leaflet polygon object, there are two arrays "_originalPoints" and "_parts", I was wondering if anyone knew what the purpose of these two arrays were.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm Leaflet author.

_originalPoints is an array of projected geographical points (screen coordinates of the polygon points), and _parts is an array of arrays of points that eventually gets rendered after clipping and simplifying points. In case of polygon different "parts" are needed to render holes in polygons, and in case of polylines you often get several paths out of one after clipping (cutting points off a certain rectangular area for performance).

Comment: @user1472224: If an answer has solved your issue you can accept it to indicate that. To quote: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask : `Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community.`